# AndroidDriver cant be initialized after mvn clean

Tags: selenium, appium, appium-android, appium-java

As usually, before running `mvn test` i executed `mvn clean`, but this time a lot of things started downloading, once it finished i ran the code and got this error:

```
class org.openqa.selenium.Platform$22 cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (org.openqa.selenium.Platform$22 is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

I actually didnt change anything, it just stop working (Last time I checked that this worked was 1 week ago)

This is the code that generates the error:

```
DesiredCapabilitiescap = new DesiredCapabilities();
URL url = new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub");
cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
cap.setCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5554");
cap.setCapability("avd", "Pixel_4_API_30");
cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.myapp.dev");
cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.myapp.splash.SplashActivity");
cap.setCapability("appWaitActivity","com.myapp.fulllogin.WelcomeActivity");
cap.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
cap.setCapability("noReset", "false");
AppiumDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(url, cap);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be version incompatibilities. When I got the same error, I made the following changes and it worked:

In the `pom.xml` upped the version of `java-client` to `8.1.0` and added additional dependency `selenium-support` with compatible version `4.2.0`

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

Optionally, made changes to the way capabilities are set for platform. Replaced `capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "android")` with
`capabilities.setCapability("appium:platformName", MobilePlatform.ANDROID)`

```
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobilePlatform;
...

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
...
capabilities.setCapability("appium:platformName", MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
```